# Elasticsearch query on a nested field with condition

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch v7.0

Hello and good day!

I'm trying to create a query that will have a condition: if a nested field has only 1 element, get that first element, if a nested field has 2 more or elements, get a matching nested field condition

Scenario:

I have an index named  `socialmedia`  and has a  **nested**  field named  `cms`  which places a sentiment for that  **document**

An example document of the  `cms`  field looks like this

```
"_id" : 1,
"cms" : [
    {
      "cli_id" : 0,
      "cmx_sentiment" : "Negative"
    }
]
```

This  `cms`  field contains  `"cli_id" : 0`  by default for its 1st element (this means it is for all the clients/users to see) but sooner or later, it goes like this:

```
"_id": 1,
"cms" : [
    {
      "cli_id" : 0,
      "cmx_sentiment" : "Negative"
    },
    {
      "cli_id" : 1,
      "cmx_sentiment" : "Positive"
    },
    {
      "cli_id" : 2,
      "cmx_sentiment" : "Neutral"
    },
]
```

The 2nd and 3rd element shows that the clients with  `cli_id`  equals to  **1**  and  **2**  has made a sentiment for that document.

Now, I want to formulate a query that if the client who logged in has no  **sentiment**  yet for a specific document, it fetches the  **cmx_sentiment**  that has the  `"cli_id" : 0`

**BUT** , if the client who has logged in has a  **sentiment**  for the fetched documents according to his filters, the query will fetch the  **cmx_sentiment**  that has the matching cli_id of the logged in client

for example:
`the client who has a cli_id of 2, will get the cmx_sentiment of **Neutral** according to the given document above`

`the client who has a cli_id of 5, will get the cmx_sentiment of **Negative** because he hasn't given a sentiment to the document`

**PSEUDO CODE**  :

If a document has a sentiment indicated by the client, get the  `cmx_sentiment`  of the  `cli_id`  == to the client's ID

if a document is fresh or the client  **HAS NOT**  labeled yet a sentiment on that document, get the element's  `cmx_sentiment`  that has  `cli_id`  == 0

I'm in need of a query to condition for the pseudo code above

Here's my sample query:

```
"aggs" => [
    "CMS" => [
        "nested" => [
            "path" => "cms",
        ],
        "aggs" => [
            "FILTER" => [
                "filter" => [
                    "bool" => [
                        "should" => [
                            [
                                "match" => [
                                    "cms.cli_id" => 0
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                "bool" => [
                                    "must" => [
                                        [
                                            // I'm planing to create a bool method here to test if cli_id is equalis to the logged-in client's ID
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "aggs"=> [
                    "TONALITY"=> [
                        "terms"=> [
                            "field" => "cms.cmx_sentiment"
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Is my query correct?

The problem with the query I have provided, is that it **SUMS** all the elements, instead of picking one only

The query above provides this scenario:

**The client with cli_id 2 logs in**

Both the **Neutral** and **Negative** `cmx_sentiment` are being retrieved, instead of the **Neutral** alone

Answer (score 1):

**After the discussion with OP I'm rewriting this answer.**

To get the desired result you will have to consider the following to build the query and aggregation:

#### **Query:**

This will contain any filter applied by logged in user. For the example purpose I'm using `match_all` since every document has atleast one nested doc against `cms` field i.e. for `cli_id: 0`

#### **Aggregation:**

Here we have to divide the aggregations into two:

1. default_only
2. sentiment_only

**default_only**

In this aggregation we find count for those document which don't have nested document for `cli_id: <logged in client id>`. i.e. only those docs which have nested doc for `cli_id: 0`.
To do this we follow the steps below:

1. `default_only` Use filter aggregation to get document which does not have nested document for `cli_id: <logged in client id>` i.e. using `must_not` => `cli_id: <logged in client id>`
2. `default_nested` : Add sub aggregation for nested docs since we need to get the docs against sentiment which is field of nested document.
3. `sentiment_for_cli_id` : Add sub aggregation to `default_nested` aggregation in order to get sentiment only for default client i.e. for cli_id: 0.
4. `default` : Add this terms sub aggregation to `sentiment_for_cli_id` aggregation to get counts against the sentiment. Note that this count is of nested docs and since you always have only one nested doc per cli_id therefore this count seems to be the count of docs but it is not.
5. `the_doc_count`: Add this `reverse_nested` aggregation to get out of nested doc aggs and the count of parent docs. We add this as the sub aggregation of `default` aggregation.

**sentiment_only**

This aggregation give count against each sentiment where `cli_id: <logged in client id>` is present. For this we follow the same approach as we followed for `default_only` aggregation. But with some tweaks as below:

1. `sentiment_only` : `must` => `cli_id: <logged in client id>`
2. `sentiment_nested` : same reason as above
3. `sentiment_for_cli_id`: same but instead of default we filter for `cli_id: <logged in client id>`
4. `sentiment`: same as `default`
5. `the_doc_count`: same as above

#### **Example:**

```
PUT socialmedia/_bulk
{"index":{"_id": 1}}
{"cms":[{"cli_id":0,"cmx_sentiment":"Positive"}]}
{"index":{"_id": 2}}
{"cms":[{"cli_id":0,"cmx_sentiment":"Positive"},{"cli_id":2,"cmx_sentiment":"Neutral"}]}
{"index":{"_id": 3}}
{"cms":[{"cli_id":0,"cmx_sentiment":"Positive"},{"cli_id":2,"cmx_sentiment":"Negative"}]}
{"index":{"_id": 4}}
{"cms":[{"cli_id":0,"cmx_sentiment":"Positive"},{"cli_id":2,"cmx_sentiment":"Neutral"}]}
```

**Query:**

```
GET socialmedia/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "default_only": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "cms",
                "query": {
                  "term": {
                    "cms.cli_id": 2
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "default_nested": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "cms"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sentiment_for_cli_id": {
              "filter": {
                "term": {
                  "cms.cli_id": 0
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "default": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "cms.cmx_sentiment"
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "the_doc_count": {
                      "reverse_nested": {}
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sentiment_only": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "cms",
                "query": {
                  "term": {
                    "cms.cli_id": 2
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sentiment_nested": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "cms"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sentiment_for_cli_id": {
              "filter": {
                "term": {
                  "cms.cli_id": 2
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "sentiment": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "cms.cmx_sentiment"
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "the_doc_count": {
                      "reverse_nested": {}
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Agg Output:**

```
 "aggregations" : {
    "default_only" : {
      "doc_count" : 1,
      "default_nested" : {
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "sentiment_for_cli_id" : {
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "default" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "Positive",
                "doc_count" : 1,
                "the_doc_count" : {
                  "doc_count" : 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sentiment_only" : {
      "doc_count" : 3,
      "sentiment_nested" : {
        "doc_count" : 6,
        "sentiment_for_cli_id" : {
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "sentiment" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "Neutral",
                "doc_count" : 2,
                "the_doc_count" : {
                  "doc_count" : 2
                }
              },
              {
                "key" : "Negative",
                "doc_count" : 1,
                "the_doc_count" : {
                  "doc_count" : 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for your answer! However, I'm in need of aggs coz im formulating a report. I'm not particularly aiming for the documents per se, but for the `doc_count` so I could display as a chart in my application

Comment: You actually want the count or you want the sentiment value for each doc after some filters are applied or for all the sentiments you want the doc count?

Comment: only the count sir @OpsterESNinjaNishant , 'coz my original goal for this app is to generate a report

Comment: additionally, according to your answer, I should not be able to get the **Negative** sentiment coz client 2 has already made a sentiment to that document. Instead, he should be getting only the **Neutral** sentiment

Comment: @Suomynona My question is this: If there are 4 docs in total. doc 1 with `cms` having no nested doc with `cli_id: <logged in cli_id>` and have sentiment `positive` for `cli_id: 0`,  doc 2 have `cli_id: <logged in cli_id>` with `sentiment` value as `neutral`, doc 3 has sentiment as `negative` and doc 4 `neutral` for`cli_id: <logged in cli_id>`. Now what count you want: `{default: 1, with_sentiment : 3}` OR `{"positive": 1, "neutral": 2, "negative" 1}` ?

Comment: actually the example above are all for 1 `doc` sir, they're all just elements of the *nested* field called **cms**, but presuming that we have a mutual understanding  -> there will never be more than 1 element for a specific client, coz the cmx_sentiment will just be overwritten or updated by the application, so to cut your example, it will just go back to `{"cli_id" : 0, "cmx_sentiment" : "Positive"}, {"cli_id": 2, "cmx_sentiment" : "Neutral"}` (presuming again that the logged in cli_id is 2, and "Neutral" was the last sentiment of that client) the count will get {"neutral": 1}

Comment: @Suomynona Thats why in the comment I gave example of 4 docs? If you can clear on that then I would be able to help better.

Comment: in your example sir, you said at the start of the statement ` If there are 4 docs in total. doc 1 with cms having no nested doc with cli_id: <logged in cli_id> and have sentiment positive for cli_id: 0` I didn't get this portion, coz you mentioned *having no nested doc* then there's a part you mentioned *have sentiment positive for cli_id :0*. What's confusing to your sir again? Is there a chat here in StackOverflow so we can communicate seamlessly

Comment: @Suomynona join the chat [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205405/discussion-between-suomynona-and-opster-es-ninja-nishant-and-suomynona)